Music.app can't locate music library after booting macOS
When macOS Ventura 13.4 starts up and Music.app is run, it can't locate my music library. If I simply click the "Choose Library" button, it starts up as if nothing happened. If I instead force close this window and re-launch Music.app, the music library will also open without any other issue. In other words, the music library does not open right away after the system is started and Music.app is launched, but after specifying its location.
The music library is located on the system disk. I've tried creating a new music library, as well as moving it to another disk and googling about this problem, but to no avail, apparently, it's some kind of local issue on my computer. I don't remember when this started to happening, and don't have any other Mac with Music.app to test.
The problem only occurs after another system boot. If I specify the library location once or force close Music.app and open it again it runs without a problem until the next system boot. I think there's something in the system autorun that prevents the Music.app to locate its library. Any ideas of how can I check this or look through the logs to see what's happening when the app is trying to launch after mac boots up?

